# Linux networking not working after playing a game on Windows

Tags: networking, dual-boot, ethernet

I have this bizarre problem with my PC. Linux networking stops working after I play a
game on Windows.

### Situation

I have dual boot, Windows 10 for gaming and Manjaro linux for day-to-day use.
I'm using a cable connection to my router, so it is fast and stable.
I bought a new game recently, and my typical PC use looks like this:

- I turn on my PC and boot into linux for a few hours of work
- I reboot into windows, and I'm playing this game for like an hour or so
- I reboot into linux again

After I switch back to linux and I try to use the internet, it stops after
downloading a few hundred KB of data (maybe around 1 MB, hard to say exactly).

### Trying to debug and fix

When it first happened, I thought it was some router issue or ISP problem.
But no, other devices in my home network worked fine so not ISP. Cable itself
and router are fine too because the internet works all the time on Linux after first
boot and also on Windows when gaming. Other things I tried:

- Disconnect and connect using network applet ❌
- Restart networking service `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` ❌
- Unplug and plug network cable again ❌
- Reboot into linux again ❌
- Reboot into windows (internet works) and reboot into linux ❌
- Turn off PC, wait a few seconds, and then start it into linux ❌
- Turn off PC, **cut off electricity, wait like 30s, switch electricity back**, boot PC into linux ✅

The only way to make the internet work again is to cut off electricity,
and then boot into linux.

That looks like it is a hardware problem, but on the other hand, the internet
works fine on Windows even just after playing game. I was also thinking
that maybe something was overheating, but again, even after turning off my PC for
a few hours (without cutting off electricity), it is still not working on Linux.

I can't figure out what is going on. Do you have any idea what could be the cause?

### Debug info

```
$ uname -a
Linux piotrek-pc 6.5.13-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 28 20:33:05 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

----

$ journalctl -p 3 -b0 
gru 05 23:29:12 piotrek-pc colord-sane[1041]: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1

----

$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

----

$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager.service
[sudo] password for piotrek: 
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-12-05 23:29:11 CET; 1h 3min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 943 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 19101)
     Memory: 20.1M
        CPU: 233ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─943 /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.5796] device (vethb5f8884): carrier: link connected
gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.5798] device (docker0): carrier: link connected
gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.5799] device (enp30s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.5809] device (enp30s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.5810] device (enp30s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.5812] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.5814] device (enp30s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.5818] manager: startup complete
gru 05 23:29:14 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815354.6467] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
gru 05 23:29:16 piotrek-pc NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1701815356.0664] agent-manager: agent[f36462a8b096765f,:1.35/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1000]: agent registered

----

$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp30s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:86:19:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp30s0
       valid_lft 86140sec preferred_lft 86140sec
    inet6 fe80::6bad:f8d:8529:725d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

----

$ journalctl -p 3 -b0 -o short-iso
2023-12-06T17:52:47+0100 piotrek-pc colord-sane[1034]: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1

----

$ sudo dmesg -T --level=emerg,alert,crit,err,warn --time-format iso
2023-12-06T17:52:36,153817+01:00 ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): Optional FADT field Pm2ControlBlock has valid Length but zero Address: 0x0000000000000000/0x1 (20230331/tbfadt-615)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,153947+01:00 Speculative Return Stack Overflow: IBPB-extending microcode not applied!
2023-12-06T17:52:36,153947+01:00 Speculative Return Stack Overflow: WARNING: See https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/srso.html for mitigation options.
2023-12-06T17:52:36,328872+01:00 mtrr: your CPUs had inconsistent variable MTRR settings
2023-12-06T17:52:36,467031+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,467146+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,467245+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,467425+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,467588+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,467754+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,467910+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,468064+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,468211+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,468367+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,468547+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,468705+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,468859+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,468979+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,469114+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,469249+01:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI MWAIT C-state 0x0 not supported by HW (0x0)
2023-12-06T17:52:36,480090+01:00 amd_pstate: the _CPC object is not present in SBIOS or ACPI disabled
2023-12-06T17:52:41,636165+01:00 vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
2023-12-06T17:52:41,679047+01:00 VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
2023-12-06T17:52:41,680999+01:00 VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
2023-12-06T17:52:42,529751+01:00 r8168  Copyright (C) 2023 Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
                                  This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details, please see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>. 
                                  This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>. 
2023-12-06T17:52:49,704231+01:00 ksplashqml[1546]: memfd_create() called without MFD_EXEC or MFD_NOEXEC_SEAL set


----


$ sudo lspci -v -d ::0200
1e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33, IOMMU group 12
        I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
        Memory at fe604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at fe600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: r8168
        Kernel modules: r8169, r8168
```

// EDIT

I did some testing and seems like gaming has nothing to do with this. It is Windows 10 that breaks networking somehow after reboot. I noticed that my router see my PC even after shutdown so probably network card is still working. After I cut off electricity and wait like 30s my router connection led is not active any more and then networking is working on Linux again.

Is there any way to disable network card right after shutdown? I tried to search in BIOS but could not find option.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "networking not working", can you narrow this down? From the errors, it seems that name resolution is broken. Can you `ping 8.8.8.8` successfully while in the broken state?

Comment: Any Firmware Error in Journal?

Comment: @Panki Not sure if read my post carefully but as I said it is like ping is working just after I login. But when I try to open any webpage or download like 1MB of data, ping stops working and whole networking is down. After some time network applet shows that network is unreachable. I cannot even ping my router. Basically ethernet card stops working.

Comment: @nobody I could not find anything related to network and firmware in `journalctl`

Comment: Please can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078711/switch-pci-device-to-d3-cold-d3cold-state  if something can revive your netcard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question because I was able to finally fix it. I found [this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/update-to-r8168-8-051-02-1-breaks-network-access/147625) on Manjaro forum and that lead me to checking what driver I'm using. `lspci` show two kernel modules available `r8169` and `r8168`. And somehow I was using older module. I checked few more things and found this:

```
$ ls -la /etc/modprobe.d/
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4,0K 12-07 08:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 131 root root  12K 12-07 17:21 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   16 2018-07-30  r8169_blacklist.conf
```

inside

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/r8169_blacklist.conf
blacklist r8169
```

Somehow new module was blacklisted. I checked in `pacman` who owns this file and it belongs to no package. Probably some leftover from some old package that is not here any more. I renamed this to `/etc/modprobe.d/r8169_blacklist.conf.disabled`, rebooted, and now networking works fine even after using Windows. Still not sure what changed on Windows that it broke my networking. Anyway, good that it works.

Thanks everyone for your answers and interest in my problem.

Comment: But how did Windows write to a (presumably) Linux file system?

Comment: @JeremyBoden It didn't (especially when linux partitions are encrypted). The problem happened probably because something changed in windows network driver and it put hardware in "unrecognized state" that my old linux driver version could not handle. Hardware state was "reset" after I turn off electricity and waited some time so it worked with old driver until I used windows again. The new network driver on linux was blocked by blacklist file that was probably some leftover after package I installed and removed. Don't know which one tho. Using new driver on linux fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

*Sometimes* Windows may set a device (your network chip) to an internal state that the Linux driver cannot recover.    Try doing a fill power-down rather than a reboot (where power is maintained).

Comment: The problem is that even when I do a shutdown the problem still persist. I need to cut down electricity altogether and wait like 30s to make it work again. Is it possible somehow to disable this power setting in Windows?

Comment: When you shutdown, some devices retain power, including ethernet devices. This is why you can send wakeup packets to start a computer remotely. Disconnecting the power allows the ethernet to reset itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Windows' Fast Startup feature and shutdown.**

When dual-booting with any Windows 8.x or newer disabling Fast Startup in Windows is a must.

The more typical problem created by that "feature" is making NTFS partitions (and sometimes even FAT32 - e.g. the ESP -) in an hibernated state.

Occasionally, and depending on the actual hardware and firmware (UEFI) or firmware settings, it can also "hijack" network devices.

Comment: I checked and I don't have such option at all on my PC, so nothing to disable.